# Need to add buffer records into a CSV files to provide filler between gaps in record IDs

Tags: sql, csv, excel-2007

I have a CSV file that contains about 2,000 customer accounts. Unfortunately, the Customer IDs do not start from 1 and are not in order. As an example the Customers IDs are in this order after sorting (2, 3, 12, 19, 23, etc.)

Is there any feature within MS Excel 2007 or SQL or any other application/tool that can fill the gaps among the CustomerIDs? I can use some dummy data for the customer name, address, etc. for the records that were filled.

Answer (score 0):

Import data to excel.  Use formula to fill down column A such that no numbers are skipped.

- Use vlookup to populate columns that match based on ID
- blanks / #N/A are records you need to fix
- Save back out as CSV (done)

Row 8 shows the formula's I used
C1:D3 is the lokup values so you can see 1,3, 5 were populated 2 4, 6, 7 were not

[image]

Comment: Your solution is fine but ideally I want to have Excel generate a new row for the missing ids. This will ensure all the rows are kept intact.